# Install specific version of google-chrome-unstable

Tags: google-chrome

I am using the following as part of a Dockerfile for installing google-chrome (based on [this](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-in-docker)):

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget --no-install-recommends \
    && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y google-chrome-unstable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst ttf-freefont \
      --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && apt-get purge --auto-remove -y curl \
    && rm -rf /src/*.deb
```

However, rather than just install the latest version, I'd like to install a specific version.  Is this possible?  I tried the following:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget --no-install-recommends \
    && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y google-chrome-unstable=66.0.3346.8-1 fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst ttf-freefont \
      --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && apt-get purge --auto-remove -y curl \
    && rm -rf /src/*.deb
```

The only difference is adding an explicit version number `=66.0.3346.8-1`.

But I get:

```
E: Version '66.0.3346.8-1' for 'google-chrome-unstable' was not found
```

Using an explicit version number corresponding to the latest version worked, so I suspect that older versions are simply not available via this source?

Answer (score 11):

```
apt-get update
apt-get install wget
wget http://dl.google.com/linux/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-unstable/google-chrome-unstable_73.0.3679.0-1_amd64.deb
apt-get install -f ./google-chrome-unstable_73.0.3679.0-1_amd64.deb
```

You can find the version numbers here
https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/google_chrome/stable/main/base/google-chrome-unstable